# "Double free or corruption(out)" on closing a file?

Tags: c, file, multidimensional-array, malloc

I wrote a code to exercise on various arguments (files, dynamic bidimensional arrays, passing pointers to functions etc) so don't mind if some passages seem useless. 
At runtime, if I input more than 3 lines the program crashes and terminal says "Double free or corruption (out)" and then core dump created. The error should happen on the fclose(fp) in foo2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo1(int *);
void foo2(int*,int,int**,FILE*);
void readfoo(FILE *, int **, int);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int **a, i, j, r, c, *pr, *pn, *pc;
    pc = &c;
    pr = &r;
    foo1(pr);
    a = malloc(r*sizeof(int));
    foo2(pc,r,a,fp);
    if((fp = fopen("column.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, can't open \"column.txt\"");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%d", &c);
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "insert line %d column %d -> ", i+1, j+1);
            fscanf(stdin, "%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    if(fclose(fp) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, can't close \"column.txt\"");
        exit(1);
    }
    readfoo(fp,a,r);
    remove("column.txt");
    return(0);
}

void foo1(int *r)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "how many lines ? -> ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", r);
}

void foo2(int *c, int r, int **a, FILE *fp)
{
    int i,j, act_c;
    if((fp = fopen("column.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, can't open \"column.txt\"");
        exit(1);
    }
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "how many columns for line %d? -> ", i+1);
        fscanf(stdin, "%d", c);
        fprintf(fp,"%d\n", *c);
        a[i] = malloc((*c)*sizeof(int));
    }
    if(fclose(fp) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, can't close \"column.txt\"");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void readfoo(FILE *fp, int **a, int r)
{
    int c, i, j;
    fprintf(stdout, "printing the matrix... \n");
    if((fp = fopen("column.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, can't open \"column.txt\"");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%d", &c);
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    }
    if(fclose(fp) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, can't close \"column.txt\"");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: _fp_ is given not initialized, can be removed from parameter to be a local var in _foo2_

Comment: You're probably closing `fp` twice. Shouldn't be too hard to find out how. Or you're overwriting memory that doesn't belong to you and you get UB afterwards. 2nd,3rd and 4th line of `main` are fishy.

Comment: please give us the contents of _column.txt_ and the values read from _stdin_ to be able to run you rprogram

Comment: @Diragon please do what we have asked for: [edit] your questiom and add a minimal sample of `column.txt` that reproduces the problem. Show the file, don't describe it's content.

Comment: I also already tried to put all foo 2 in main so there isn't no passage of variables but it gives me the same error at runtime. Column.txt is created  by the prigram and stores the columns for each line, which is given by input in stdin, and it's  deleted by the prgram at it's end.

Comment: @Diragon when you give it in argument to _foo2_ it is not initialized, this is both disturbing (why doing that ?) and useless. JUst use a local variable into _foo2_ and remove it from the parameter. When I read you code I first imagined you used it to read before to nitialize it

Comment: @Jabberwocky I did the same error but not, r is initialized by foo1 using a pointer to it

Comment: @bruno right, but the code is really weird.

Comment: @Jabberwocky hehe yes, it is not easy to read ^^

Comment: Yeah guys sorry for the not so easy-to-read code, but as I said I'm exercising ono various arguments and I'm trying to implement all of them in one code despute it being clear. Theoretically it should work anyway, but it olnly works if i create a bidimensional array with only 3 or less lines. That's really weird :/

Comment: @Diragon I did some tests without problems, if you hope an answer give us the inputs producing the error !

Comment: @bruno any input bigger than 4 at the question "how many lines?" in foo1, but the error itself come out at closing the file in foo2 (i tried inserting some printfs between lines of the code)

Comment: IN your code you never write in column.txt, why do you open it in write mode ?

Comment: @Diragon this is false, if I enter 5 then after all the times 1 there is no problem. You refuse to give us inputs even we required several times ? this is your problem, I will not use more time in these conditions ...

Comment: I tried to run the program on a friend's computer and it gives us the same error. Could it be an error by our compilator version? I really don't know how to make it run properly huh

Comment: @Diragon: C language seems rather tolerant on input, because some inconsistencies do not generate errors. But they often lead to Undefined Behaviour, meaning that for example a program could run fine in one context and crash misrably in a slightly different context. So ensure you only write strict valid C where 1D arrays, 2D arrays and arrays of pointers are not mixed. `int **a;` declares a pointer to pointers that should be used for arrays of pointers, while `a = malloc(r*sizeof(int));` allocate a 1D array of `int` values. Fix that first and come back.

Comment: @Diragon the bug is in your code and not in the compiler for sure. Please post a minimal version of `columns.txt` as requested multiple times.

Comment: As mentioned a few times, please provide your input. Also provide the file "column.txt" that is created.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ? What is the expected format of columns.txt ? Why don't you name your variables properly ? Why don't you use a squared matrix ? Here is a `pedagogic` example inspired from your code: `https://pastebin.com/Vnk5LMFL`

Comment: @Tezirg thanks a lot, you put a lot of effort in this reply. I'll try to rewrite the code following your advice and in case i'll repost it here

Comment: @Tezirg I rewrote my code without using pointers and all t

Answer (score 1):

in `main()` you do

```
 a = malloc(r*sizeof(int));
```

That's wrong it should be

```
 a = malloc(r*sizeof(int *));
```

That invokes UB if you assign values to `a[i]` and could be thre real reason for the crash

Comment: I deleted the comment in the meantime. The OP's code is really weird.

Comment: Oh yes it really is